# How to shift the csv Column from column A to Column D using the java?

Tags: java, excel, csv

I'm facing issue in the csv.  If im having four Column like  `ColumnA`, `ColumnB`, `ColumnC`, `ColumnD`.  I need to shift the entire columns like `ColumnD`, `ColumnC`, `ColumnB`,`ColumnA`.

```
Column A should Shift to Column D
Column B should Shift to Column C
Column C should Shift to Column B
Column D should Shift to Column A
```

How to do it in the Java??

Comment: What did you try? Consider documenting on Apache POI.

Comment: @zenbeni : Yet to start, it is possible in Apache POI ?